# Creating files while writing html in sublimetext2 (creating files from scope)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I noticed a useful feature while watching angular.js how to video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WuiHuZq_cg4#t=56s

That feature is creating a file (filename + file extention) based on what you write in html/css code.

Is this possible with sublime text2? If so, is there such plugin i could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watched the how-to video and did find this feature useful. Inspired by this, I created a plugin that emulates this behavior:

https://github.com/gregsadetsky/NewFileFromScope

(installation instructions appear in the plugin description text, near the bottom)

---

Shortly, this plugin adds a "New File From Scope" command to the Command Palette which will pseudo-smartly try to extract a file name from the current scope, and create a new file named correspondingly.

For instance, if you have the following line:

`<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">`

placing your cursor anywhere in the *app.css* text (or selecting it) and invoking the command will create a new, empty file named "app.css".

Enjoy!

Comment: this definately saves time a bit, ill try to scrub in when i find some time (hope to create folders this way if its gonna be possible) :)

Comment: Creating folders shouldn't be too hard -- use posixpath's 'split' function to get directory names, and create them as necessary (i.e., when they don't already exist). I've documented another possible addition [here](https://github.com/gregsadetsky/NewFileFromScope/issues/1): this would allow to invoke the command with the cursor positioned anywhere on the line, not specifically at the 'app.css' text.